# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am new to rust and I am building a TUI app using rust-tui to practice and understand the concepts of rust. I have this code:

```rs
// the widgets that can be renderd on the screen
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Widgets<'a> {
    ResList(ResList<'a>),
    ListResults(ListResults<'a>),
    Input(Input),
}

pub struct Screen<'a> {
    renders_done: u32,
    tx: Sender<Result<Event, crossterm::ErrorKind>>,
    rx: Receiver<Result<Event, crossterm::ErrorKind>>,
    main_screen: Widgets<'a>,
}


impl Screen<'_> {

    pub async fn handle_events(&mut self) {
        let event = self
            .rx
            .recv()
            .expect("Err while recievent the events in the reciever")
            .unwrap();

        let new_screen: Option<Widgets> = match &mut self.main_screen {
            Widgets::ResList(res_list) => {
                match event {
                    Event::Key(event) => match event.code {
                        KeyCode::Esc => {
                            Screen::exit_app();
                            None
                        }
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
            Widgets::Input(input) => input.handle_events(event).await,  <-- the problem comes when I add this
            _ => None,
        };
        match new_screen {
            Some(screen) => self.main_screen = screen,
            None => {}
        }
    }

}
```

```rs
impl Input {
    async fn handle_events(&mut self, event: Event) -> Option<Widgets> {
       None
    }
}
```

The idea is that if a sub-module returns a widget the main screen should be changed to that new widget. For texting purposes for now I never return a widget.
But when I try and build the code the compiler complains:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
   --> src/model/tui/screen.rs:84:32
    |
84  |     pub async fn handle_events(&mut self) {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the method body at 84:32...
   --> src/model/tui/screen.rs:84:32
    |
84  |     pub async fn handle_events(&mut self) {
    |                                ^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
   --> src/model/tui/screen.rs:84:32
    |
84  |     pub async fn handle_events(&mut self) {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: expected `&mut Screen<'_>`
               found `&mut Screen<'_>`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 45:13...
   --> src/model/tui/screen.rs:45:13
    |
45  | impl Screen<'_> {
    |             ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
   --> src/model/tui/screen.rs:126:52
    |
126 |             Some(mut screen) => self.main_screen = screen,
    |                                                    ^^^^^^
    = note: expected `Widgets<'_>`
               found `Widgets<'_>`

error: aborting due to previous error; 8 warnings emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
```

From what I understand the lifetimes are not living enough to be saved in the struct but I am not using references anywhere they are all owned values. Can someone help me understand what am I missing?

Comment: *"From what I understand the lifetimes are not living enough to be saved in the struct but I am not using references anywhere they are all owned values."*

Note that for any struct `S<'a>` with a lifetime parameter `'a` it must be the case that `S<'a>` lives as long as `'a`, not just for references. `input.handle_events(event).await` returns something that might not live as long. I would recommend explicitly giving a name to the lifetime on `impl Screen` to get a better error message.

Comment: Thanks, now I have other borrowing errors but I think specifying the lifetime in the &'a mut self worked, I'll post an answer later after I've completely solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the lifetimes explicitly on the widget returned and create an explicit lifetime of the object:

```rs
impl<'screen> Screen<'screen> {

    pub async fn handle_events<'c>(&'cmut self) {
        let event = self
            .rx
            .recv()
            .expect("Err while recievent the events in the reciever")
            .unwrap();

        let new_screen: Option<Widgets<'screen>> = match &mut self.main_screen {
            Widgets::ResList(res_list) => {
                match event {
                    Event::Key(event) => match event.code {
                        KeyCode::Esc => {
                            Screen::exit_app();
                            None
                        }
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
            Widgets::Input(input) => input.handle_events(event).await,
            _ => None,
        };
        match new_screen {
            Some(screen) => self.main_screen = screen,
            None => {}
        }
    }

}
```

Also add the lifetime explicitly when returning a Widget from inside a function